# Get Family (relationship) To Facebook User using FQL not working

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I want to get family relations form Facebook

1. i get user permission "friends_relationships"
2. My Code go like this:

   ```
   FacebookWebClient facebookWebClient = new FacebookWebClient();

   string fql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, family FROM user WHERE uid = me() ";

   dynamic friendsInfo = facebookWebClient.Query(fql);
   ```

My problem is that the family is always return null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the family info, you should request for the "user_relationships" perm.